# How to search data in a pivot table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I created a pivot table from a dataframe using:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df , index=['student','year','subject'] , values=['mark'])
```

and I got a table like this:

```
student       year        subject 

'Martin'      2014        Algebra      5
                          Chemistry    3.5 
                          Programming  8

'Sara'        2013        Algebra 2.2
 ....         ....        .....
```

How can I get Martin 2014 Algebra's mark?

I tried as a dataframe:

```
 t[t.student=='Martin'][t.year=2014][t.subject==Algebra]
```

but it doesn't works

Can somebody help me? Thank's!

Comment: I doubt **everybody** can help... but **somebody** surely can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the resulting pivot table is just another dataframe.  However, this dataframe has a multiindex.  Multiindexes can be referenced with tuples of the levels.  This is @psidom's and @TedPetrou's answers

---

However, an alternative would be to use the [`xs` cross section method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)

```
table.xs(('Martin', 2014, 'Algebra'))
```

---

In this particular case, table is really a Series.  You can use `query` on a dataframe.  So we can make it a dataframe and then `query`

```
table.to_frame().query('student == "Martin" & year == 2014 & subject == "Algebra"')
```

Comment: Bummer, beat me to it

Comment: @AndrewL keep trying

Answer (score 6):

You have a multi-index data frame, use `loc` with tuple to access the value:

```
table.loc[("'Martin'",2014,"Algebra")]
```

Comment: Thank you! you have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the index in order to use boolean indexing

```
t= table.reset_index()
t[(t.student=='Martin') & (t.year=2014) & (t.subject=='Algebra')]
```

Or you can use MultiIndex Selection

```
table.loc[('Martin', 2014, 'Algebra')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Pd.: the second option is better than the first because in the first option you change the format of the table

Answer (score 0):

Multi index in pivot table will cause issue to your statement, please use below

```py
table.loc[('Martin', 2014, 'Algebra')]
```